# Display Objects Related Objects Reference In Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have two classes with a one-to-many relationship:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='students', default=None, null=True)
```

In Django Teacher's Admin page (THIS-> /admin/users/teacher/ , NOT THIS -> /admin/users/teacher/1/change/) I'd like to either:

- List all a Teacher's students

or

- Display the total number students a Teacher has

I would usually add fields to this page using something like:

```
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'teacher',)
```

But as this is a one-to-many relationship and im accessing the 'many', im lost.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to add the number of students to the teacher list view, you can add a read only field (just the same as you would for the change view)

```
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'teacher','student_count')

    def student_count(self, obj):
        return obj.students.count()
```

This should do the trick.

In this case, `obj` refers to the specific instance of the `Teacher` object in each row. You could adapt the function above, to return a list of students. I'm not sure this would look particularly good on the `Teacher` list view page though. Probably best to keep it to things that can fit easily on one row.

Comment: This is prefecter than perfect. Thank you

Comment: :) glad it helped